# AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames

Tags: .net, identity, role

Having followed the instructions in various posts regarding setting the a.NET Identity UserManager to accept emails as a username, all was fine until I tried to add a user to a Role.

```
 Dim um = New UserManager(Of ApplicationUser)(New UserStore(Of ApplicationUser)(New ApplicationDbContext()))
 result = um.AddToRole(user.Id, role)

 result.Errors = "User name xxxx@xxxxx.com is invalid, can only contain letters or digits."
```

It would appear that I need some code similar to

```
Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New(New UserStore(Of ApplicationUser)(New ApplicationDbContext()))
    Users = Store
    UserValidator = New UserValidator(Of ApplicationUser)(Me) With {.AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = False}
End Sub
```

That relates specifically to the Roles Validation. Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Just an update, I tried my code with a alphanumeric username and the role was added correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing at the syntax from doing this in c#, but this is how I solved this problem:

```
Dim um = New UserManager(Of ApplicationUser)(New UserStore(Of ApplicationUser)(New ApplicationDbContext()))

' Add this line ...
  um.UserValidator = New UserValidator(Of ApplicationUser)(Me) With {.AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = False}

 result = um.AddToRole(user.Id, role)
```